# Java compile questions with directories with spaces?

Tags: java, compilation

I'm getting the following issues when trying to compile my .java file.  Here is the cmd line that I'm using.  I think it has something to do with "." any ideas?

```
javac -g -classpath "C:\Python27\";"C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\lib\thirdparty";"C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\lib\jdbc";"C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\API\robosuite-java-api\lib";"C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\lib";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin" Basicrobot.java
```

Error I'm getting - Invalid Flag Javac: Files\Kapow

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Cygwin or the normal Windows shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the backslash after `C:\Python27`, which means the quotation character following it is escaped.

You can simply omit the backslash:

```
javac -g -classpath "C:\Python27";...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:\Python27\"
```

The `\"` is escaping that quote so it skips over it and continues until `;"`

You need to escape the slash instead e.g. (notice the `\\`)

```
javac -g -classpath "C:\Python27\\";"C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\lib\thirdparty";"C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\lib\jdbc";"C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\API\robosuite-java-api\lib";"C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\lib";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin" Basicrobot.java
```

Comment: There should single qoutes for the whole classpath. See @paulsm4's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Does it work when you put the WHOLE classpath in double quotes, and you DON'T use trailing slashes?

```
javac -g -classpath "C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\lib\thirdpart;C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\lib\jdbc;C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\API\robosuite-java-api\lib;C:\Program Files\Kapow Mashup Server 6.4\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin" Basicrobot.java
```